# Discord Python Change region

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

sorry if this is such a DUMB question but i'd like to know what's wrong with this command, as i'm getting `discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "EnumMeta" failed.` as an error. What does the error exactly mean and what would be the correct command?

```
@commands.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_server=True)
async def region(self, ctx, region=discord.ServerRegion):
    """Changes the server region."""
    if not region:
        await self.bot.say("What region are we changing to, {ctx.message.author.mention}?")
    await self.bot.edit_server(region)
    await self.bot.say("Ok! We're now in " + str(ctx.message.server.region) + " :smiley:")
    print('ok')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in converter for `ServerRegion`.  Fortunately, we can make one that gets the job done fairly easily by using the fact that `ServerRegion('amsterdam')` is equivalent to `ServerRegion.amsterdam`:

```
region_converter = lambda region: discord.ServerRegion('-'.join(region.lower().split()))

@commands.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_server=True)
async def region(self, ctx, *, region: region_converter=None):
    """Changes the server region."""
    if not region:
        await self.bot.say("What region are we changing to, {ctx.message.author.mention}?")
        return
    await self.bot.edit_server(ctx.message.server, region=region)
    await self.bot.say("Ok! We're now in " + str(ctx.message.server.region) + " :smiley:")
    print('ok')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ServerRegion' object has no attribute 'icon'` shows up, however :(

Comment: @DanielCasares Try changing your `edit_server` line to `await self.bot.edit_server(ctx.message.server, region=region)`.  You should also add a `return` in the `if`, so you don't try to edit the server if `region` isn't set.

Comment: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.server' has no attribute 'region'` am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @DanielCasares It's working for me.  What line is that error on?

Comment: `await self.bot.say("Ok! We're now in " + server.region + " :smiley:")
AttributeError: module 'discord.server' has no attribute 'region'` This is giving the error, your code works fine though, thank you so much! I've been going crazy because of this

Comment: `ctx.message.server.region`, not `server.region`.  Are you doing `from discord import *`?  Usually you shouldn't be importing that module.

Comment: No, i didn't import that module

Comment: It's fixed now! Thank you SO much