# How to change Discord voice channel region? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am looking for a way to change the region of the voice channel using discord.py
But I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I think it is no longer possible to change the region of a voice channel.

Comment: the answer might be already found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271632/discord-python-change-region , but as @redystum mentioned, the region option has been removed from discord recently

Comment: Where do you see that the region option has been removed? I still see it in the [official discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#modify-channel) as well as the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the people who helped me discover the answer.

The valid solution is:

```
await channel.edit(rtc_region="region's name")
```

for regions that contain 2 words, should be written like this:

```
await channel.edit(rtc_region="us-central")
```

instead of Hong Kong and South Africa, it should be written like this:

```
await channel.edit(rtc_region="southafrica")
await channel.edit(rtc_region="hongkong")
```