# Changing server region

Tags: python, discord

In `discord.py`, how do I change the RTC region of a Discord server?

```py
@edit.command()
async def region(ctx, *, region_name: str):
     await ctx.guild.edit(rtc_region=region_name)
```

The function should give you the possibility of changing the server region via "!edit region -region name-"

Error Text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\DiscBot\Command Basics.py", line 70, in region
    await ctx.guild.edit(rtc_region=region_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Guild.edit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rtc_region'
```

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Format your question properly.

Comment: Yeah, I have formatted my question wrongly. Sorry for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272730/9288580

Comment: @NikolajŠ. that answer is 5 years old, it doesn't apply. That method doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [The documentation for discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit), that method indeed doesn't have an `rtc_region` argument.

The Discord API documentation [says](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild) that modifying the `region` of a guild is deprecated. This is probably why `Guild.edit` doesn't support this.

Instead, you can change the region of each individual channel with:

```py
await voice_channel.edit(rtc_region="us-central")
```

For more information see [the documentation for `VoiceChannel.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.edit).